# Spring Data JPA Specifications - Distinct + order by column in join

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I have some specifications that I am combining with "and":

```
Specification.where(predicate1).and(predicate2).and(predicate3);
```

One of them has distinct set :

```
query.distinct(true);
```

Another one makes an order by on a column that is in a join.

```
query.orderBy(builder.desc(bJoin.get("orderbyColumn")));
```

This fails with a **SQLGrammarException** stating that order by column should be in distinct.

So basically we have entity A, the main entity, and some nested entity B, we select from A but want to order by B, and in generated sql it only selects columns from A. The only way I found to make it work (= making it select from B as well) is to replace the join by a fetch :

```
Fetch < A, B > bFetch = root.fetch("joinCol", JoinType.INNER);
Join < A, B > bJoin = (Join < A, B > ) bFetch;
```

that worked for some time, was testing locally in H2, but then after some time started getting another error :

> org.hibernate.QueryException: **query specified join fetching, but the
> owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list**

I solved it somehow in my local pointing to H2 by requiring some columns to not be null, but in real server using PostgreSQL, it's not working at all, getting that error for all cases when a fetch is present.

My question is : what is the right way to use **distinct** along with **orderby** on a nested entity that is not fetched? Is my solution with **fetch** ok and it just needs to be fixed (and if so how?) or I should go for another option entirely?

For the actual query I am using this method :

```
findAll(Specification<>, Pageable)
```

Isn't there a way to have **distinct** wrapping the whole query with order by (some sort of subquery?) and bypassing all this nightmare? Have it generate a query like this:

```
select distinct colA1, colA2, coAl3 from (select colA1, colA2, coAl3 

from A inner join B b on ........ order by b.colB1)
```

Do I need to convert my specification to predicate manually and do something else with it to try to solve my issues (some kind of hybrid approach)?

Any pieces of advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, it helped me a lot. There is any idea how to handle it in some deep way? Multiple fetches cause multiple bag exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered same error but actually it was not error :)

findAll(Specification<>, Pageable) this method throws 2 different queries.

First one is count query where you have to be careful.
Second is the rows query where you actually did it.

You can check the query type with code below

```
if (query.getResultType() != Long.class && query.getResultType() != long.class){
   root.fetch("entity1");
}
```

Comment: Hi, will try it shortly, thank you. Just to be sure , when you say same error you mean the one related to the fetch ? (I listed error about fetch and about distinct ) So you put that in code that uses fetch or in all of your specifications  ?

Comment: First query is count query that's reason you are getting error.

Comment: you can use fetch in if clause

Comment: Thank you, will try it now, might have to play with my code a bit since as you can see above I am converting to fetch to join, but I'll base wether to this regular join or fetch join on that condition you gave, will report quickly, thanks again.

Comment: Last question, where is that documented? I mean for someone just genuinely trying to make this work, is that actually documented somewhere? Or is it trial and error from people debugging that issue?

Comment: I don't know it is documented  or not but I found it while debugging.